# How do I beat Level 130?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I can't seem to figure out what do I have to do to beat level 130? I don't understand what the objective is. I have played level several times and I don't understand what the symbol is.

Answer (score 4):

So in this objective, it's quite simple, You have to combine 5 strip candy combos together.

You can make a Striped Candy by placing 4 similar candies together. Once the striped candy is formed, you need to make a separate Striped Candy, the combine those 2 together.

So essentially to beat this level, you need to make 10 stripped candies, and combine 5 pairs together.

[image]

Example: Here you can see the 2 striped combos are next to each other, and after you swap them, you'll only have 4 to go.

[image]

Comment: As a comment, in a position shown on last screenshot, you should swipe down, not up, to avoid killing the Striped candy on the left. This is a common mistake many people would make. Also, forming a Striped candy on the right side first may be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time as well to figure it out. There are some smart tricks you need to know to complete Level 130. In level 130 there are only 40 moves available, so you need to be careful with them.

Tip 1: Get the Striped Candies in Level 130
Combine four or more candies with each other and you'll get a special candy. Those special candies are important to get all the objectives of this level.

To get the Striped balls at the top of the play field you have to make 5 CANDY combinations.

In order to complete this level quick, you need to get two striped candies in the playfield and try to combine them in one move. A very big part of the playfield will get blown away.

Tip 2: Only play the Striped Candies when they can be played together.
One very important tip for Level 130 is; Don't play the striped candy when they can't match with each other. Wait for the right moment until the special candies can be matched with each other in one move.

This will give you the right moves which you need to accomplish this Level in Candy Crush. When you play the special candies the wrong moment this could cost you a live in the game.
- See more at: http://progameguider.com/candy-crush-saga-level-130/

Answer (score 0):

You should play more from the bottom to shuffle the candies. Combine more same color candies to get special candy to break them. You can get help by watching the video here http://candycrushmom.com/level-130/